# Growth Curve Modeling in Lavaan vs Mplus

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I would like to replicate analyses that I have done in M*plus* 8 using `lavaan`.

## M*plus* script:

```
TITLE:    First stab;
DATA:     FILE = dataLong.csv;
VARIABLE: 
   NAMES = PtIDNo weeklyscore baseline 6month SGstatus Txhalf rmssd1 rmssd2 sd1 sd2 BDIr1 BDIr2 BDIor ID Sess Sesslog;
   USEVAR = weeklyscore Sess SGstatus rmssd1 sd1 baseline 6month;
   CLUSTER = PtIDNo;
   MISSING = all (-99); 
   WITHIN = Sess;
   BETWEEN = SGstatus rmssd1 sd1 baseline 6month;
   USEOBSERVATIONS = Txhalf eq 1;
DEFINE: center rmssd1 sd1 baseline(grandmean);
ANALYSIS:   
   TYPE = TWOLEVEL RANDOM;
   ESTIMATOR = ml;
MODEL:
   %WITHIN%
   s|weeklyscore on Sess;
   %BETWEEN%
   s with weeklyscore;
   6month on baseline s SGstatus rmssd1 sd1;
OUTPUT:  
   tech1 tech3 sampstat standardized cinterval pat svalues;
```

## Lavaan script:

```
firsthalfmodel.1 = "

i =~ 1*Sess0 + 1*Sess1 + 1*Sess2 + 1*Sess3 + 1*Sess4 + 1*Sess5 + 1*Sess6 + 
1*Sess7 + 1*Sess8 
s =~ 0*Sess0 + 1*Sess1 + 2*Sess2 + 3*Sess3 + 4*Sess4 + 5*Sess5 + 6*Sess6 + 
7*Sess7 + 8*Sess8 

# Regressions
6month~baseline+s+SG+sd_1+rmssd_1"
```

## Question:

Can I correlate the slope with the weekly score in `lavaan`, in the same manner as I did in M*plus*?